# Adding flags to highcharts (same as highstock)

Tags: highcharts

See topic here: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=22151&p=87009&hilit=13701#p87009

and the link which refers to the answer (which no longer works):
http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13701

Could someone help me find/reproduce the answer, I'd like to add flags to highcharts just as is possible in highstock charts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Highstock library and Highcharts chart like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SUH26/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
//parameters
});
```